# Is it possible to dynamically build a table using PHP?

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to dynamically build a table using PHP?

I am using code such as the below to build tables etc. but as there are multiple I was wondering in this case is it possible for the table to be built dynamically based on the SQL query?

For example if I need to build another table then I can copy the below code and just edit the SQL rather than also editing the column headers etc. in the HTML.

Basically some method to simplify the below code so that it is more compact\tidier if being used multiple times on the same page.

### Code

```
  <?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  include('core/connection.php');

  if($conn){

  $stid = oci_parse($conn, "

    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
      SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4
      FROM t1
      ORDER BY c1
    )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 10

  ");
  oci_execute($stid);

  echo "<table class='table table-hover '>
        <thread>
        <tr>
        <th>c1</th>
        <th>c2</th>
        <th>c3</th>
        <th>c4</th>
        </tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody>";

  while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['0'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    unset($row);

  }

  echo "</tbody>
        </table>";

  oci_free_statement($stid);
  oci_close($conn);

  }
```

Comment: Create a `tablify` class or function? something like `tablify($headings, $rows);` ? It really depends on how complex you want to go...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

First example on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible , but you are doing it wrong. *HTML* that you `echo` is not valid (some *HTML* elements have a required closing tag like `<table></table>` so you should output `<table>`  and `</table>` in one `echo`). One of the options for you is to assign your dynamic *HTML* to a value and then echo the *valid HTML*.

```
$buffer = "<table class='table table-hover '>
           <thread>
              <tr>
                 <th>c1</th>
                 <th>c2</th>
                 <th>c3</th>
                 <th>c4</th>
              </tr>
           </thread>
           <tbody>";

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM)) {
   $buffer .= "<tr>
                 <td>" . $row['0'] . "</td>
                 <td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>
                 <td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>
                 <td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>
               </tr>";
   unset($row);
}

$buffer .=  "</tbody>
             </table>";
echo $buffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like jQuery DataTables, http://datatables.net/ - it will allow you build the table from a JSON-object that you have made with PHP (i.e. by using json_encode() on your SQL result).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents on it:

```
function DisplayRawDataset( $dataset, $connection) {


    $res = !is_resource($dataset) ? mysqli_quert($dataset) : $dataset;

    if ( !is_resource($res) ) return  '';

    $i = 0;
    $retstr = "";
    $retstr .= "<table" border=\"1\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" >";
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

        if($i == 0){
            reset($row);
            $retstr .= "<tr>";
            while(list($key, $val) = each($row)){
                $retstr .= "<th><b>".htmlspecialchars($key)."</b></th>";
            }
            $retstr .= "</tr>";
        }
        $retstr .= "<tr>";
        reset($row);
        while(list($key, $val) = each($row)){
            $retstr .= "<td>".htmlspecialchars($val)."</td>";
        }
        $retstr .= "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    $retstr .= "</table>";
    return $retstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U could probably do this

```
$return = "<table class='table table-hover '>
        <thread>
        <tr>";
foreach(oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM) as $key){
$return .= "
        <th>".$key."</th>
";

}
$return .= "
</tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody>
<tr>";

foreach(oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM) as $key => $value) {


    $return .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";


  }


$return .= "</tr>
</tbody>
            </table>";
}

echo $return;
```

or something along this line...

Answer (score 0):

I use this....

```
<?php
/**
    @file:      tableFunctions.php
    @version:   1.0


*/
//Initialize $headersPrinted boolean
$headersPrinted = false;

function obj2Table($obj, $id, $loop)//Passed arguments should include the object, the id for the created table, and '1' for the default first loop
{
    global $headersPrinted;
    $print = false; 
    if ($loop == 1)
    {
        //Setup a table to output the object
        echo "<table id=\"$id\" border='.5'>\r\n";
    }
    //Loop through the object
    foreach ($obj as $name => $value) 
    {       
        //Check for nested objects
        if (is_object($value))
        {
            //If it is a nested object, feed the child back through
            obj2Table($value, $id, 0);
        }//end if(is_object)
        //Check for nested arrays
        elseif (is_array($value))
        {
            //If it is a nested array, try to feed each array back through
            foreach ($value as $arrayKey => $arrayValue)
            {
                obj2Table($arrayValue, $id, 0);
            }       
        }//end elseif(is_array)
        else
        {
            //Set the $print boolean to true to print the rows once the foreach ends            
            $print = true;
            if (!$headersPrinted)
            {
                $keys[] = $name;                
            }
            $cells[] = $value;                      
        }//end else
    }//end foreach  
    if ($print)
    {       
        if (!$headersPrinted)
        {
            echo "<tr>\r\n";
            foreach ($keys as $key)
            {
                echo "<th>$key</th>\r\n";
            }
            echo "</tr>\r\n";
            $headersPrinted = true;         
        }           
        foreach ($cells as $cell)
        {
            echo "<td>$cell</td>\r\n";  
        }
        echo "</tr>\r\n";
    }   
    if ($loop == 1)
    {
        //Close the table
        echo "</table>\r\n";
        //Set the $headersPrinted boolean back to false
        $headersPrinted = false;
    }//end if(initialLoop)
}//end function obj2Table() 

?>
```

The just `include` that file in your php.  In your `while` statement for the query results, just add each row to an array like this.. `$results[] = $row;`.  After the `while` loop, then send the results to the function like this... `obj2Table($results, 'queryTable', 1);`.  NOTE: you would need to change your `oci_fetch_array` to `oci_fetch_object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
$sql = "SELECT field1 as 'Colunm 1', field2 as 'Colunm 2', fieldn as 'Colunm n' FROM table;";

function buildTable($sql){
    $tab = "";
    $head = "";
    $body = "";
    if (is_string($sql) && $sql !== "") {
        $qry = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
            if ($head == "") {
                $head = "<tr>";
                foreach ($fet as $key => $val) {
                    $head .= "<th>{$key}</th>";
                }
                $head .= "<tr>";
            }
            $body .= "<tr>";
            foreach ($fet as $key => $val) {
                $body .= "<td>{$val}</td>";
            }
            $body .= "</tr>";
        }

        return "<table><thead>{$head}</thead><tbody>{$body}</tbody></table>";
    }
}

echo buildTable($sql);
```